# How do I know when user disconnects with express server

Tags: javascript, express

I have an node express server that I use as a backend to support an instant chat feature on my website. The issue I have is when someone closes out their browser, their status does not get updated to 'offline' on their friend's buddy list. I know there is a function in node called req.on('close', function(){}); but I'm just not sure how to include it in my server file. Any hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Here is a snippet of my express server code that I think is relevant:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());    
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
next();
});

app.use(require('./middleware/im')({
maxAge: 60 * 1000,
reapInterval: 60 * 1000,
    authentication: require('./libs/authentication/' + AUTH_LIBRARY) 
}));


    app.set('root', __dirname);
```

// Listener endpoint; handled in middleware
    app.get('/listen', function(){});

```
app.post('/message', function(req, res) {
    res.find(req.body['to'], function(user) {
        if(!user)
           return res.send(new packages.Error('not online'));
        res.message(user, new packages.Message(
        req.session.data('username'),
        req.body.body
    ));


});
```

});

```
app.post('/message/typing', function(req, res) {
if(~packages.TYPING_STATES.indexOf('typing' + req.body['state'])) {
    res.find(req.body['to'], function(user) {
        if(user) {
            res.message(user, new packages.Status(
                req.session.data('username'),
                'typing' + req.body.state
            ));
        }

        // Typing updates do not receive confirmations,
        // as they are not important enough.
        res.send('');
    });
} else {
    res.send(new packages.Error('invalid state'));
}
```

});

```
app.post('/status', function(req, res) {

if(~packages.STATUSES.indexOf(req.body['status'])) {
    res.status(req.body.status, req.body.message);
    res.send(new packages.Success('status updated'));
} else {
    res.send(new packages.Error('invalid status'));
}
});



    app.post('/clear', function(req, res) {

    app.use(require('./middleware/im')({
       clear: req.sessionID,
       maxAge: 60 * 1000,
   reapInterval: 60 * 1000,
   authentication: require('./libs/authentication/' + AUTH_LIBRARY)
}));
    req.sessionID = null;
res.send(new packages.Success('cleared session'));
app.use(require('./middleware/im')({
   clear: 0,
       maxAge: 60 * 1000,
      reapInterval: 60 * 1000,
    authentication: require('./libs/authentication/' + AUTH_LIBRARY)
```

}));

});

```
app.post('/online', function(req, res) {
 var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getTime() + 60;
 req.sessionID.expires = n;
 res.status(req.body.status, 'available');
  res.send(new packages.Success('Online'));
```

});

```
app.post('/signoff', function(req, res) {
res.signOff();
res.send(new packages.Success('goodbye'));
```

});

```
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, so it doesn't have any concept of 'connected user'. You need to use some sort of client-side mechanism to notify your server when a user is navigating away (perhaps use an `onbeforeunload` handler which posts a message to the server). The `close` event you mention isn't useful, unless you're using some sort of long-polling mechanism (but I don't think you are).

To implement chat, a better solution might be [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/), which maintains a permanent connection between the browser and the server and has built-in mechanisms to notice if a browser has closed the connection (in case the user navigated away, for instance).

Comment: Here's a description of using `socket.io` for chat: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/  and a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNKNYLv2BpQ

Comment: Do you know if it is difficult to replace Ajax calls in my client side code with socket.io? I think this is something I definitely need to do. Socket.io is just seems so much better.

Comment: @ArjunPatel is depends on the complexity of your AJAX calls, but generally isn't not a huge problem.

Comment: Ok got it. I'm a a little confused now. If HTTP is a stateless protocol, does that mean it won't know when a session has expired?

Comment: @ArjunPatel that's right. When a session cookie expires, the browser just won't send it to the server anymore, but the server won't know if the browser *used* to have a cookie or not. Hence, it won't know if it's dealing with a new visitor or with a previous visitor whose session expired.